# getting the id of a rendered html in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a rendered html using jquery and I when I was testing it I tried to console.log the selected value of the select dropdown but I couldn't get it. Can you tell me what's wrong with my code or why it's not logging the selected value?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      //date forms
          $("#datetypediv").html("<select required name='date_select' class='form-control' id='date_select_off'>"
                                  + "<option val='daily'>Daily</option>" +
                                    "<option val='monthly'>Monthly</option>" +
                                    "<option val='quarterly'>Quarterly</option>" +
                                    "<option val='annually'>Annually</option>" + "</select>");

        if($('#date_select_off option:selected').val() == "daily") {//value attribute
          console.log('daily');
        }

});
```

The whole thing is a typo

```
<option value=""></option>
```

Comment: instead of val='daily' please write value='daily' (same go for others)

Comment: Also you can just use `$('#date_select_off').val() == 'daily'`

Comment: @RohithKP yes it is

Comment: omg you are right. thank you for this.

Comment: use <option value=""></option>

Comment: Please, edit your post so people do not waste time answering something purely due to a typo :)

Comment: Maybe choose a title that has something to do with the question?

Comment: @freedomn-m I don't havve the right to create a vote for now

Comment: @freedomn-m or if I do, I do not know how to cast it :)

Comment: @Sorikairo my bad - I forget what access levels are needed for what: looks like you can see the close votes, but not yet vote: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is proper HTML syntax

```
<option value=""></option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/csharpbd/vhcnqb7h/).

Change if condition `daily` to `Daily`.

Code:

```
if($('#date_select_off option:selected').val() == "Daily") {//value attribute
  console.log('daily');
}
```

```js
$("#datetypediv").html("<select required name='date_select' class='form-control' id='date_select_off'>"
                              + "<option val='daily'>Daily</option>" +
                                "<option val='monthly'>Monthly</option>" +
                                "<option val='quarterly'>Quarterly</option>" +
                                "<option val='annually'>Annually</option>" + "</select>");

    if($('#date_select_off option:selected').val() == "Daily") {//value attribute
      console.log('daily');
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="datetypediv">

</div>
```

Comment: Don't use link-only answers.

Comment: I'm not provide only link. I've worked and tested then provide the link.

Comment: It's also false as val() (with the proper html syntax) would return the value 'daily' and not the text inside the option element 'Daily'

Comment: @csharpbd the point is that the work you've done should be included here, in SO, not on a 3rd party website that may or may not be available in the future.

Comment: I've added the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You are matching with `option attribute` use with  `.attr('val')` not `val()` . if you need match the `val()` .change the syntax `<option value="daily"></option>`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

      //date forms
          $("#datetypediv").html("<select required name='date_select' class='form-control' id='date_select_off'>"
                                  + "<option val='daily'>Daily</option>" +
                                    "<option val='monthly'>Monthly</option>" +
                                    "<option val='quarterly'>Quarterly</option>" +
                                    "<option val='annually'>Annually</option>" + "</select>");

        if($('#date_select_off option:selected').attr('val') == "daily") {//value attribute
          console.log('daily');
        }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="datetypediv"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating dom element so not directly getting value by using id. You can call like this.

```
$(document).on('change','#date_select_off',function(){
    if($(this).val() == "daily") {
      console.log('daily');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running all of this code inside a document ready function, so it will run the value checker after inserting it, so, if you have the following code in the selector `$('#date_select_off option:selected').val()`, the `:selected` its pointing no element, since none of the options has the selected attribute.

I think you should have `<option value="#" selected></option>` in order to get a value in this console log

Comment: Look again, if there's no `selected` value, the `:selected` selector will point to the first entry.